# How to get each registration type from the array?

Tags: php

I have an array with the request data that has these name and surname arrays:

```
"name" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "Jake"
        ]
        4 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "John"
        ]
      ]
      "surname" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "W"
        ]
        4 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "K"
        ]
      ]
      ]
```

I want to insert each participant name, surname and registration_type_id where the participant is being registered in the participants table. Like this it seems that is possible to store the name and surname of each participant. But how to get the registration_type_id of each participant (in this case 1 for Jke and 4 for John)?

```
foreach ($request->all()['name'] as $key => $name) {

            $participant_result = Participant::create([
                'name' => $name[1],
                'surname' => $request['surname'][$key][1],
                'registration_type_id' => how to get this???
            ]);

        }
```

The registration_tpye_id for the participant Jake is "1" and for John is "4" as it is in the array:

```
"name" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "Jake"
        ]
        4 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "John"
        ]
      ]
      "surname" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "W"
        ]
        4 => array:1 [▼
          1 => "K"
        ]
      ]
```

Additionally Provided sample data

```
"name" => array:2 [
    1 => array:2 [
        1 => "Jake" 
        2 => "John"
        ] 
    4 => array:1 [
        1 => "Adam"
        ]
    ]
    "surname" => array:2 [
        1 => array:2 [
            1 => "W" 
            2 => "K"
            ] 
    4 => array:1 [
        1 => "L"
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: `'registration_type_id' => $key` ??

Comment: Thanks, like that it works for the example in the question wtih 2 participants, the participant John being registered in the registration type with id "1" and participant Jake being registered in the registration type "4". But if the user is registering 2 participants in the registration type with id "1" and 1 participant in the registration type "4" the array is like ""name" => array:2 [▼ 1 => array:2 [▼  1 => "Jake"  2 => "John" ] 4 => array:1 [▼ 1 => "Adam"]]
  "surname" => array:2 [▼ 1 => array:2 [▼  1 => "W" 2 => "K" ] 4 => array:1 [▼ 1 => "L"]
  ]".

Comment: But in that case only Jake and Adam are registered. The participant John is not inserted in database. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `$key` variable in the foreach loop.

```
...
'registration_type_id' => $key
...
```

**UPDATE:-** As per your provided Data set, you shall have to parse it as below.

```
foreach ($request->all()['name'] as $key => $nameArray) {
    foreach ($nameArray as $nameKey => $name) {
        $participant_result = Participant::create([
                    'name'                 => $name,
                    'surname'              => $request['surname'][$key][$nameKey],
                    'registration_type_id' => $key
        ]);
    }
}
```

**WHY:-**  Since the users are grouped under the `registration_type_id` as a sub array with their user-ids as keys (*I suppose, not sure though so named them `$nameKey`*), we have to also loop through the sub-array.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why if the user is registering 2 participants in the registration type with id "1" and 1 participant in the registration type "4" the array is like ""name" => array:2 [▼ 1 => array:2 [▼ 1 => "Jake" 2 => "John" ] 4 => array:1 [▼ 1 => "Adam"]] "surname" => array:2 [▼ 1 => array:2 [▼ 1 => "W" 2 => "K" ] 4 => array:1 [▼ 1 => "L"] ]".  only Jake and Adam are registered. The participant John is not inserted in database. Do you know why?

Comment: @John Updated my answer.